# OSX text-to-speech: key words are badly synthetise in French. How to overcome?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, text-to-speech

OSX has a great Text to Speech (TTS) feature, but I noticed some limitations.

I set OSX 10.9.2 in French with French TTS voices. The words "pages", "user", and pseudo-word "fire" for example are not pronounced correctly (English pronunciation with a French accent).

The command line I use in Terminal is

```
say -v Aurelie "pages" -o out.aiff
```

I am not familiar with the inner mechanics of TTS, but is there a manipulation to overcome this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!